# Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^3 = O$, but $A^2 \ne O$. Show that $\{I,A,A^2\} \subset M_{n \times n}(\Bbb R)$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^3 = O$, but $A^2 \ne O$. Show that $\{I,A,A^2\} \subset M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ is linearly independent.

**Attempt:**
Is the $O$ above denotes the zero matrix in $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb R)$?

Let $k_1,k_2,k_3 \in \Bbb R$ such that
\begin{equation*}
k_1I + k_2A + k_3A^2 = O \ldots (1)
\end{equation*}
By adding both sides of $(1)$ by $I$, we have
\begin{equation*}
(k_1+1)I + k_2A + k_3A^2 = I \ldots (2)
\end{equation*}
Now, multiplying both sides on the right by $A$, we have
\begin{equation*}
(k_1+1)A + k_2A^2 + k_3A^3 = A
\end{equation*}
or, equivalent, as
\begin{equation*}
(k_1+1)A + k_2A^2 = A.
\end{equation*}

I got stuck there. Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $xI+yA+zA^2=0$, we deduce that $A^2(xI+yA+zA^2)=xA^2=0$, we deduce that $x=0$ since $A^2\neq 0$.

We also have $A(yA+zA^2)=yA^2=0$, we deduce that $y=0$ and $zA^2=0$ implies $z=0$.

Comment: Well, thanks yow!

Comment: yes it is linearly independent

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

From $aA^2+bA+cI_n=0$, multiply by $A^2$. What do you get ?

Comment: $aA^4 + bA^3 + cA^2 = O$ or $aAA^3 + bO + cA^2 = O$ or $aAO + cA^2 = O$. But, $A^2 \ne O$. Hence, $c=0$. Like this?

Comment: Okay, got it right now. Thanks!